# UV Plasmon Resonance

Tags: plasmon

Are there any techniques available for getting thin films of gold(or any other metal that is resistant to oxidation) to generate plasmon resonances in the shortwave UV-C region?

Comment: Are you looking for a chemically resistant variation of this kind of system: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/nn400918n?

Comment: You might ping Professor Rashid Zia at Brown Univ.  That's close to his areas of research

Comment: @CuriousOne:Just resistant to oxidation, if I understand your comment correctly.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Thanks Carl, how convenient, Brown is only 10 minutes from home :-)

Comment: Got it. I hope you can find a suitable system! May I ask what you are doing? Just out of curiosity, I can't give any valuable input.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Sorry Mr. Curious, I can't tell you what its for, it's proprietary :-(

Comment: I had a hunch! Best of luck!